# REST - Define name for JSON array from Restful Java Service

Tags: java, json, rest, glassfish

I got the following function in my REST Java service running in a Glassfish Server:

**serviceTest.java**

```
@Path("/servicetest")
public class serviceTest{
    @GET
    @Path("/findall")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Person> findAll(){
        List <Person> result = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add(new Person("1", "Charlie");
        result.add(new Person("2", "Mary");
        return result;
        }
    }
```

Also I have defined a class:

**person.java**

```
public class person {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    public person(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

When I called the `findAll()` function from the client side or a web browser, I'm getting the following JSON object in this format:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Charlie"    
    },

    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Mary"  
    }
]
```

But I need to identify the JSON array by a name, something like this:

```
{"person":
    [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Charlie"    
        },

        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Mary"  
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I do this...? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the person list in a map:

```
public Map<String,List<Person>> findAll(){
    List <Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Person("1", "Charlie");
    list.add(new Person("2", "Mary");
    LinkedHashMap<String,List<Person>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("person", list);
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but now I'm getting this error: `HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error. The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.`

Comment: @CyborgNinja23 search the log files for a stack trace

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `List<Person>` in a class with a single field:

```
public class PersonResponse {

    private List<Person> person = new ArrayList<Person>();

    public PersonResponse(List<Person> person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

}
```

And change your REST method to:

```
public PersonResponse findAll(){
    List <Person> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add(new Person("1", "Charlie");
    result.add(new Person("2", "Mary");
    return new PersonResponse(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason, when I wrap it in this class, it gives me the 'Status 500 - Internal Server Error'